# The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK - IntelliJ on MacOS

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I try to add a new Java on IntelliJ I'm receiving the following message: "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK".

When I run `which javac` the output is `/usr/bin/javac`. And when I run `ls -la /usr/bin/javac` the output is:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Apr 13 14:29 /usr/bin/javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
```

I tried to add both `/usr/bin` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/` as a home for JDK but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give JAVA_HOME directory in which you installed your JDK, not the path containing `javac`. It should be `Java_Installed_Dir` NOT `Java_Installed_Dir/bin/javac`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appropriate way to find the Java home on a Mac is to go into Terminal and type:

```sh
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

This will give you a result which you can set as your Java home directory. For example, on my Machine, it displays:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, but in Ubuntu. If you are in MAC, is quite similar.
The thing is that firstly you must install the jre and jdk.

I have it in my `/usr/lib/jvm`

Then, after that, you must put the variable $JAVA_HOME in your $PATH in the ~/.bashrc file at the end. But I found that after adding my jre and my jdk, my IDE didn't detect my jdk. So what I do to solve this in my IDE was:

In your command line:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME='/your/path/without/bin'
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If no problem was detected and all is fine, just do

```
java --version
```

If is detected, next, go to the other step:

=> Open your IDE. In this step, if your IDE doesn't recognize java version or SDK (as in my case), do the following

```
javac --version
```

This is where I solved the problem, becouse it looked like I didn't have javac, so I solved it with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-<version>-jdk-headless
```

=> Then open your IDE and select the SDK you have just installed. It's like the IDE doesn't recognize de previous JDKs.